# Should I use soil-less technology for growing my veggies?

Tags: vegetables, soil

I recently started growing some veggies in my farm, when I saw the soil-less growing techniques. If I am doing it purely for hobby and just working on the farm myself and not looking to spend 1000's of dollars, then should I consider using the soil-less technology for growing my veggies?

Comment: I can't answer the question but I think it would be helpful to others if you could specify what exactly you mean by "Soil-Less Technology" as that could mean a few different things. Broadly hydroponics and aeroponics with variations in each. Also if you plan on selling the tomatoes at market or growing them just for yourself and at what scale.

Comment: To add to OrganicLawnss comment, Auqaponics (another soil-less) was something I tried two summers back.  It is also soil-less and was fun to try it once with the food and fish being something even the kids enjoyed. It can be expensive to start, even with the cheap items.  What is your budget? And what do you want to get out of this, just to try it out (taste test) and see if its a hobby or did you want to go larger?  My answer to your final question is "YES, you should consider it"  but your question is so broad that I am not sure you will get an Answer.

Answer (score 3):

DIY and small scale soil-less systems are becoming rather popular, especially for out of season indoor production. In ground outdoor crops are still far more economical and produce more natural produce, but I'd say if you want to grow some veggies in the off season, go for it!